# Visual Studio 2015 installer hangs during install?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the full ISO for Visual Studio Ultimate CTP 6.  The installation program got to about the 90% mark, gauging by the progress bar, and just stuck there.  There was frequent activity from Superfetch, Anti-malware protection, and other background processes, but the progress bar was dead still.  Eventually the background task activity subsided after 20 minutes, but the progress bar still wouldn't budge.

CHEAP TRICK: Open a notepad window and position the left edge of it so it perfectly marks the current position of the progress bar.  If it the progress bar doesn't move past the left edge of the notepad window in about an hour, it's probably stuck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772347/visual-studio-2015-community-edition-installation-stuck-in-windows-10/33472773#33472773 killing the enablegraphics.exe did it!

Comment: love the cheap trick LOL

Comment: well i let it run over night and get the total result in the next day morning. So damn slow installation. My PC has a CPU of Intel i5-4590 dual core 3.30 GHz and 12 GB RAM.

Comment: Wellllll over 12 hours...maybe 15.  but.... .it completed. Finally

Answer (score 235):

This was a case of one of the sub-installers getting stuck during the install and never completing.  Unfortunately when this happens, it looks like the master installer never times out the operation.  The trick is to open up the Task Manager in detail mode, and look for a sub-installer process that is showing 0% CPU usage and 0% disk usage, indicating it has died.  Then just kill that process and the master installation will resume.  In my case, the name of the sub-installer was **SecondaryInstaller.exe** and according to the installation log it happened while it was trying to install some Android SDK components for the cross platform development modules.  It had frozen permanently.  I killed it and the master installer completed.  When I ran Visual Studio it was fine, although I'm guessing I'll have to do some digging on the Android components install problem.

Comment: Initially, this did not work for me. I ended the secondary process, and the main one still was stuck. So I cancelled, and that got stuck. Then had to end that process too. Later, next time I rebooted my computer, when I logged in, suddenly the installer opened itself back up and finished, and then gave me a message telling me Setup completed successfully.

Comment: Still have this problem in VS 2015 Professional Release from July 20, killing the process seems to work

Comment: Mine waz stuck getting the Windows Phone SDK and killing the SecondaryInstaller.exe fixed it for me.

Comment: don't follow this approach it messed up my installtion

Comment: Great. Thank you. It worked for me. One important thing is to figure out the name of the process which is holding the Visual studio installer. this can be done in Task Manager. Open Task Manager in detail mode--> Go to the "Details" tab--> Right Click the VisualStudio Process-->Click on the "Analyze wait chain". You will see the name of the process which is responsible for the wait. Kill this process and hopefully your installer will proceed quickly. good luck!

Comment: Got stuck twice - both on SecondaryInstaller. Continued after killing each time

Comment: And the exact problem is described here - but Microsoft misunderstands ir and proposes solutions from VS itself but not how to solve it on the installer runtime - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75f1399d-4bc6-4314-8e3c-458468657ba9/visual-studio-2015-rc-installation-stuck-for-more-than-24-hours

Comment: Do not do it. JUST WAIT.

Comment: This broke Visual Studio. I had to remove and install it from scratch.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this having had it stuck for an hour without moving. Then it moved!

Wait but whinge so that they feel it next time. Really is too long and MS should have indicated an approximate time to install when they released it.

Comment: This is a good idea. (Different response later in this page)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31004547/1194583

Comment: In my case it was stuck installing "[KB2882822](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2882822)" for 2-3 hours. I don't see the "Analyze wait chain" option (is it a Windows 10 thing?) so I used Sysinternals Process Explorer to see "wusa.exe" was a subprocess of vs_community (which was a subprocess of vs_community). The Properties of `wusa` said it had used only 0.09 seconds of total CPU time and I found no way to tell what it was waiting _for_ so I killed it. The installer immediately did the next task, and finished soon after with two warnings about "...Azure... package failed"

Comment: This worked for me as well.  In Windows 10 pro I had 1 instance of Windows installer running and 2 instances of windows installer 32 bit running.  I ended the 32 bit processes and the installation resumed.

Comment: I was in the same situation as @Qwertie, where it stuck at installing "KB282822". After checking Task Manager and seeing `wusa.exe` process not active (0% CPU usage) for almost an hour, I decided to kill the process. The installer finally continued until it finished without errors. So far Visual Studio seems to be launching just fine (without errors). I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: I killed the sub installers, the installation is successful.  However, when I tried to compile a web site, the debugger is not working.  It asks me to repair it.

Comment: @abhinaw task manager tool chain was always showing me its dependency on `dwm.exe`. Every time I kill it, it will get reborn on its own and then VS installer again got into waiting for it to do something. I had to ultimately kill `SecondaryInstaller.exe` only as suggested in this post to go past the issue.

Comment: This is an intentional Microsoft tactic to determine whether or not you are worthy to use Visual Studio 2015. Skills required - high level of patience, StackOverflow, Windows admininstration basics.

Comment: This was the only thing that actually helped (I tried cleaning caches, stopping/starting update service, deleting updater folders, etc, etc.). Thanks.

Comment: If you kill any of the processes during install, you should run the repair option afterward, from the installer, to fix anything that may not have been properly installed. I had this issue installing VS Build Tools 2017, stuck at 99%. I killed it, reran the installer and it gave me the option to repair. The repair process completed without issue. I assume this is a networking issue. Online installers suck.

Answer (score 36):

I temporarily disabled my antivirus (AVG) and restarted the install.  That fixed it.

Comment: I had to completely uninstall AVG. Simply disabling it didn't work for me.

Comment: Same for me. Disabling AVG didn't work. But what works is - turning on/off wi-fi. That gets a stuck installer going again.

Comment: Seriously recommend this fix - I had major problems with VS 2015 Update 1 and 2 - disabling anti-virus (Avast in my case) solved the install issues

Comment: I even must remove the AVG and use the Avira instead because the AVG keeps alerting about the URL:Mail virus in the setup file.

Answer (score 23):

The current version of AVG Free antivirus is incompatible with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

1. It does not allow Visual Studio to be installed on the computer. It gets stuck at "Creating restore point". Visual Studio installs perfectly when AVG is turned off.
2. Any code compiled in "Release" mode targeting x86 platform/environment (in project properties) does not compile. It compiles successfully when AVG is turned off.

I posted the issues in AVG support forum but no one responded.

Comment: You're right. I disabled it and it installed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually this is a very good point. AVG Free is messing up other Microsoft products. I had an issue with insanely slow Outlook 2016 until disabling the add-in. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: Sometime ago Avg deleted my compiled project files from a c# sockets application. Constantly was getting in my way so I uninstalled it, I left a ticket on AVG support and aparently it was common for it to detect false positives.

Comment: I faced the same problem, and Stopping AVG during installation solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Same thing happened to me, and I also tried to terminate secondary process from task manager. **Do not do that.** It is not a solution, but rather a hack which may cause issues later. In my case, I was not even able to uninstall Visual Studio. I tried both web installation and ISO, same issue.

Here is how it worked finally. I restored my Windows 7 to earliest restore point as possible, when there was nothing installed, so I was sure that there would be no conflicts between the different tools (Java, Android API, etc.)

I started the installation of Visual Studio 2015 Community Release Candidate at 10 p.m. At 7 a.m., it was working on Android API 19-21. A hour later, it was finally preparing Visual Studio.

This means that **all you need to do is to actually wait 8 to 9 hours**. Don't terminate the secondary installer at risk of breaking your Visual Studio; just wait.

Comment: You make an interesting point that people should note.  But I had a similar problem with VS2013 and in that case I did leave it running overnight and it was still hung in the morning.  The key in both cases is that the sub-installer showed 0% CPU usage in the Task Manager, indicating it literally was "doing nothing".  So perhaps people should leave it overnight, but then, kill it if it's still hung like in my case.

Comment: but you will not be able to use the visual studio after killing the installer,do something else,run a fresh copy of windows and install it there.

Comment: That was not my experience.  After I killed the *sub-installer* (not the main installer) VS worked properly and so did all child modules it installs.

Comment: Too late... And this is a brand new fresh install of Windows 8.1, no restore points.

Comment: Indeed, I confirm that the installation can take hours (actually 11 hours for me on a 8-cores machine with an SSD and 20 GB of RAM for a basic installation, no Android), but ends without the need to terminate any process. Hopefully, I wouldn't have to install Visual Studio 2017; I certainly don't want to keep it installing for a week or two.

Comment: yeap, it took me a night. So slow installation.

Comment: I would cuation do not prematurely kill the secondary task, Wait for it at least 30 min, if it still hangs around kill it. I have the same problem of visual Studio 2015 community, failing in the last 10 % and yes there is this secondary installer which got stuck but I got a message for it and killed it but still VS2015 not installed properly.

Comment: If you are waiting 8 or 9 hours and then it completes, the installer is working fine but you have a bad internet connection. Most likely you are on wifi, which tends to get packet errors if the signal is weak or there is interference, causing the data to be re-transmitted many times. Either ditch the dialup or get a wired internet connection.

Answer (score 21):

During the installation if you think it has hung (notably during the "Android SDK Setup"), browse to your %temp% directory and order by "Date modified" (descending), there should be a bunch of log files created by the installer.

The one for the "Android SDK Setup" will be named "AndroidSDK_SI.log" (or similar).

Open the file and got to the end of it (Ctrl+End), this should indicate the progress of the current file that is being downloaded.

i.e: "*(80%, 349 KiB/s, 99 seconds left)*"

Reopening the file, again going to the end, you should see further indication that the download has progressed (or you could just track the modified timestamp of the file [in minutes]).

i.e: "*(99%, 351 KiB/s, 1 seconds left)*"

Unfortunately, the installer doesn't indicate this progress (it's running in a separate "Java.exe" process, used by the Android SDK).

This seems like a rather long-winded way to check what's happening but does give an indication that the installer hasn't hung and is doing something, albeit very slowly.

Comment: In my case I'm not even installing Android tools. It got stuck at 99.9% "Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU"

Comment: I had issue with the Android SDKs not installing because they did not use the proxy server in work.  Killing the the java.exe made the installer continue without error.

Comment: I check my log file and it says  (99%, 73 KiB/s, 0 seconds left) and its the same without any change in the file content and the date modified. Any suggestions what to do? by the way its stuck at Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 and 21)

Comment: The idea of checking the %TEMP% folder and "tailing" the log file (AndroidPackageSelectorInstall20161207-124701.log in my case) was helpful. I used Notepad++, which makes it easier to detect when the file has changed and reload it.  I switched to airplane mode long enough to get this in the file (also java.exe disappeared from Task Manager): "Stopping ADB server succeeded."

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem when I tried to install VS 2015 RC from ISO. It got stuck during Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 & 21, System Images). For me the problem was metered Wi-Fi connection. The installer didn't download necessary files.

**Turning off the Internet connection** resolved the problem. When installation finished, it said that some components were not installed and it will try to download and install them later.

Comment: This was helpful to me. I temporarily switched into airplane mode until the log file in %TEMP% reported that "Stopping ADB server succeeded." and Java disappeared from Task Manager. Other things then started showing up in TEMP, so I was glad I hadn't killed any tasks yet.

Comment: Also, search this page's comments for  "Analyze wait chain" (or "abhinaw"). That's a handy trick.

Answer (score 15):

Check if your Windows has pending updates. After the restart, installation worked as expected.

Comment: This was it for me. I had a pending restart, hit restart even though the installer was still doing its thing and it loads fine now.

Comment: Even if they are not pending, sometimes WU just starts killing the PC resources for no obvious reason. You can manually stop the service to make it recover.

Answer (score 8):

Alright so after hours of googling and failed attempts at solving this including many of the suggestions above, I found a solution I tried on a whim and worked for me.

Attempt to install the program, then, when it gets "stuck", cancel it, but don't uninstall.

Then, go to the control panel, go to programs, go and attempt to uninstall it, select "Repair" instead of Uninstall.

"Repairing" Visual Studio appears to have completely worked and was very quick, under 5 minutes and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: I did that, but repair takes forever too. Should I cancel the repair and repair again?

Comment: Do you have Windows 10 Technical Preview? I found that when I did the in place upgrade to reinstall Windows 10 that Visual Studio installed just fine.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is becoming very now, specially for users installing visual studio on windows 10 platform. What Microsoft suggests is disable your anti virus and anti malware programs and always run setup with admin permission.

But in my case I have to do lot more things to get rid of this issue:
1. Disabled AVG realtime protaction
2. Disabled AVG from task manager
3. Remove all the files and folders from system temp folder. (You can open it by typing %temp% and hit enter in run prompt)
4. Run setup again as admin

Here is a [complete list of incidents that I faced in this issue (visual studio 2015 installation got stuck)](http://www.codewithasp.net/2015/09/visual-studio-2015-installation-stuck-community-enterprise.html)

[And how I resolved it](http://www.codewithasp.net/2015/09/solution-for-visual-studio-2015-installation-stuck.html)

Answer (score 7):

I got stuck during Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 and 21) **Turning OFF and ON the Internet connection** resolved the issue and the installation completed successfully.

Comment: Is that with ISO or Internet install?

Comment: It was with internet install.

Comment: Wow. Still can't believe this actually worked. Put my Surface into flight mode and switched internet back on. The installation completed.

Comment: @Fred  Glad to know it was helpful.

Comment: This is odd. I'm not sure if it is a coincidence but it worked for me... Mine was hung at the SDK-Thing during repair.

Comment: Noting that the Java process associated with the Android SDK Setup was only receiving a measly 106 KB, once every 2 minutes, (via the Process Explorer I/O graph) I decided to follow this suggestion by suspending my active VPN connection. The VS Setup suddenly went through a bunch of CMD and Java processes and proceeded to the next step.

Answer (score 6):

My VS 2015 install hung after hours of downloading.  The VS installer window said it was still proceeding, but **Windows Resource Monitor** indicated there had been no networ, disk, or CPU usage by the vs_community.exe process tree for dozens of minutes.  **Windows Process Explorer** revealed wusa.exe at the bottom of this tree (wusa is Windows Update Standalone Installer).  Tempted to kill wusa.exe, I instead heeded the warnings in other answers to this question.

After studying other answers here (***strongly*** recommended), I made an educated guess and initiated a restart of my Windows 7 Pro.  The restart hung because vs_community.exe would not exit.  I therefore selected **Cancel** on Windows' restart popup.

Windows returned to my user session, and now the VS 2015 install came to life(!)  Process Explorer revealed wusa.exe no longer present.  I therefore suspect that was the roadblock, but my conscience is clean (*I* didn't kill wusa.exe, *Windows* did!)

After awhile the installer displayed the following:

[image]

When I clicked **Restart Now**, Windows restarted to a "Configuring Windows" screen, and completed my VS install.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is a safe mix of [killing the sub tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28788575/766570) answer and the [waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30251011/766570) answer:

- when the installer gets stuck, simply launch the task manager and kill the process
- if you attempt to run the app again, it will say that the app installation is not complete
- run the installer again, and click on `repair`
- installs fine

Answer (score 3):

When stuck on Visual Studio Preparation:

I killed vs_enterprise.exe with higher PID, Visual Studio threw an error, that "pipe is being closed". Restarted PC & Logged in. Visual Studio started automatically and has completed within 1 minute.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach to find whether one of the subinstallers is blocked is to monitor its Network and Disk I/O activity. Process Explorer from Sysinternals does an excellent job. Android SDK Setup downloads large amounts of data (more than 1GB) and the CPU sits idle waiting for an I/O-bound operation to be completed. Under no circumstances you should attempt to kill any process, or you might risk corrupting your installation of Visual Studio. In the worst case scenario, cancelling and rerunning the setup should help.

Comment: That seems to be what is happening to me. Process Explorer indicates that a subordinate Java process is receiving approximately 106 KB once every two minutes during the Android SDK setup. Shouldn't Visual Studio have fully downloaded that content before starting the SDK setup? Is there a way to force ALL the downloadable content to be fully downloaded before any installation begins (or to show download progress)?

Answer (score 2):

Mine froze on the Diagnostic Tools for 3 hours.   I tried disabling my firewall and turning off internet among many other attempts to resolve this.   In the end the following  actions allowed the installer to complete and VS2015 Community edition to launch.

- I then opened the latest log file in the %temp% folder, and navigated
  to the end of  the file.
- In the last few log lines there was an entry:  "MSI (s) (DC:4C)
  [16:28:36:577]: Created Custom Action Server with PID xxxx"
- I ended the process with the same PID, and then the installer
  continued.  I had to do it roughly 3 times in total and then the
  installer completed successfully.

All seems to be working OK so far (fingers crossed!!)

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH! I lost more than 2 days of work trying to solve the this issue, your comment saved me! I was freaking out!

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows10:**

1) Kill VS2015 Process if hung

2) Disable Windows Defender

3) Open VS2015 as Administrator

4) Enable Windows Defender

5) Initial VS2015 startup is complete

Comment: That was it for me, but there is no need to kill any processes. Just disable Windows Defender real time protection.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problems, my savior became Windows **Safe Mode**

## STEPS:

1. **Restart Windows in Safe Mode** (*run msconfig -> boot -> boot options -> *check safe boot -> mode Network*)
2. In Safe Mode:

   1. **Enable Windows Installer**:

      > REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network\MSIServer" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service"
   2. **Start Windows Installer service**:

      > net start msiserver
   3. **Run Visual Studio Updater / Installer**
3. Restart in normal mode (*run msconfig -> boot -> boot options -> uncheck safe boot*)

Comment: YES! I was trying to repair My install went from 3+ hours (quit halfway through) to 10 minutes. Safe mode does the trick. It got me to the end of my repair where it finally showed me the real error message I was trying to fix in the first place

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with the Visual Studio Update 3 installer getting stuck on the "Features" tab at ther very start of installation...it would show only "Update 2 (installed)" and nothing else, with no way to proceed.

After trying some of the other more complex advice here, it turned out, to my surprise, that all I needed to do was use "Run as Administrator" when kicking off the installer. I was under the impression MSI generally runs with Admin privileges (under the Trusted Installer service) but I suppose the VS bootstrapper in this case does not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It would hang immediately, as soon as it said "Applying Microsoft Visual Studio 2015." There was only a small sliver in the progress bar. I even let the install run overnight. There was no disk activity or CPU usage from the installer.

What finally worked was to kill the process in Task Manager and restart the computer. As soon as I rebooted, the installer opened up automatically and completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the **Graphics Tools** Windows feature installation was hanging forever.
I've installed the Optional Windows Feature manually and restarted the setup of VS 2015.

Comment: How do I do that? There's no such Feature on my list.

Comment: See this link http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/29258-graphics-tools-install-uninstall-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 1):

I just installed VS 2015 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2.  The install was fast until it reached Update 1 which is past the 90% mark on the progress indicator.  At that point, it took about 2 hours to complete.  Be patient before you try anything more radical.

Answer (score 1):

Mine got stuck applying the .NET 4.6.1 blah... Turning off the internet and disabling Microsoft Security Essentials Real-time protection got things moving again.

Comment: Downvoting a bunch of answers without leaving a comment is, to say the least, unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cant find any SecondaryInstaller.exe to stop in task manager and even I dont have any AV rather then Windows Defender so I found something else..
I stopped windows Update from elevated cmd by writing command `net stop muauserv` and it worked for me...
The update will Retry again for KB2664825 so run the code again in cmd..(because the service starts automatically)

Keep trying and its done for me...!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a different context.  After trying to repair, uninstall, and reinstall with no solution, I decided to wipe out all Visual Studio remnant by using TotalUninstaller by follower the steps by steps on the link below:

https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases

Once everything is removed, I was able to successfully install the software.

Be aware that TotalUninstaller will remove everything related to Visual Studio 2013 to 2015.  Earlier version will still be preserved.

I added this solution in case someone has the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've got same problem and unfortunately the accepted answer which suggests killing SecondaryInstaller.exe messed up installing the optional items. What I've done is basically opening the task manager and locate SecondaryInstaller.exe and right click and click on Open file location. Then run SecondaryInstaller.exe as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case UAC was disabled (the infamous regedit trick) and so the installer clearly could not handle it.

You could revert back to UAC for the installer, or simply try launching it as admin, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **windows 10**, "Windows defender" might be the reason for blocking. mine is hang while installing "*Java SE development*"

To **disable windows defender** during the installation phase:

Open Windows Defender by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button. In the search box, type Defender, and then, in the list of results, click Windows Defender.

Click Settings, and *turn off* Real-time protection.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar problems with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
In my case core issue was corrupted windows installer cache (C:\Windows\Installer)

Here is the line from msi installer log:

> MSI (s) (4C:64) [10:40:10:059]: Warning: Local cached package 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\3442502.msi' is missing.

You should check installation logs if installation cache is corrupted same way.
If it is you should pray for sfc utility to recover system integrity or you would reinstall windows from scratch as corrupted windows installer cache is a complete disaster and a reason to perform clear windows installation immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My solution was to switch off the antivirus software (Avast), download the .iso file, mount it (double click in the Windows Explorer on the .iso file), and then run it from the PowerShell with admin rights with the following switches:

.\vs_community.exe /NoWeb /NoRefresh

This way you don't have to go offline or remove your existing installation.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is there something wrong with this suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand it either. It worked perfectly fine for me. However, there is a downside. This does not solve the upgrade problem. For every upgrade you have to do the same process.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to stop the installation service forcefully using task manager. If Visual Studio was installed in Features & Programs then uninstall it, restart computer and try to install it again.

When starting the installation make sure to be have reliable internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I had also same issue, I am using Windows 10 Fall creator Edition, Set were getting stuck at some time 0% and some time 44% when it reached WIN 10SDK_10. .. file

After some research and getting into my logs files and processors in task processor i found some Power shell processor were running, I just kill the process which was not responding for long time and my setup get start working and showing progress.... that's it

I don't Know If it works for your peoples But it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The old thread with many answers. but for me, these commands solved the problem.

regsvr32.exe /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"

regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"