# Visual Studio Community 2015 RC Installation taking too long time

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've downloaded visual studio 2015 RC .iso and started installation.
But It is taking too long time.
It is around 20 hours of installation time but still it is not complete.

My machine is with intel i5 440 processor and 8GB of RAM. But still it is taking this much time.

Please note. I've selected all option in Visual Studio Community 2015 RC Installation ( Full Install )

Can anybody tell me the reason for this much amount of time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 installer hangs during install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I'm having a similar problem. It's taking an unexpectedly long time, but it has not actually become "hung". I suspect the problem is the anti-virus software.

Comment: Related: [Visual Studio long install/uninstall time?](http://superuser.com/questions/850626/visual-studio-long-install-uninstall-time), there's no solution on that question either; but note that even users that locally mounted the iso are reporting slow installs, it doesn't seem to be related to network latency.

Answer (score 2):

Simplist possible problem is that the installer has lost it's internet connection. The lovely team at MS reponsible for this installer for VS Community 2015 did not program in an error message if the internet connection is lost. It simply won't do anything, forever if it still needs to download. Once the internet connection is re-established, it'll happily download and installer some more.
Horrible oversight.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is the same as found in [Visual Studio 2015 installer hangs during install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install). Please check and do the needful. This worked for me after hours of wasting my time.