# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Installation Stuck In Windows 10

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I am trying to install VS 2015 in Windows 10 and the installation is stuck at the "Applying Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 x86 Debug Runtime - 14.0.23026" section for around 4 hours.

The Acquiring section is showing 100% though.

Terminated the same to find the below details in a log file:

```
[2015-08-02T16:48:28]i305: Verified acquired payload: 
VSSetupUtility_Complete_vs_community at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VSSetupUtility_Complete_vs_community, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\7DB2302D-A398-3430-A694-   6B1ECD9A8D22\packages\vs_community\VSSetupUtility.exe.
[0CD8:1FE0][2015-08-02T16:48:28]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[0CD8:1FE0][2015-08-02T16:48:28]i000: MUX:  Set the Cache Complete Event
[0CD8:1854][2015-08-02T19:23:22]i000: MUX:  Go to CancelPrompt page.
[0CD8:1854][2015-08-02T19:23:26]i000: MUX:  Go to Progress page.
[0CD8:1854][2015-08-02T19:28:19]i000: MUX:  Go to CancelPrompt page.
```

After "Set the Cache Complete Event" it is stuck for 3 hours...

When I look at the Task Manager details -> Analyze wait chain for the exe, it shows deadlock.

[image: Deadlock in vs 2015 setup]

This is the 3rd time I am trying to install VS 2015 community edition; 2 times using the web installer and the 3rd time using an ISO.

Comment: (Unlikely) Have you tried to drag the installation Windows? Sometimes there is just a Window hidden behind it, so check if there is.

Comment: There isn't any hidden windows

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting? It seems troubleshooting in Windows 10 is easier then ever...

Comment: vs 2015 doesn't show up in the troubleshooting window

Comment: You can try installing .MSI directly. In the ISO image it's `packages\vcRedistD14\debug\x86\vc_runtimeDebug_x86.msi`.

Comment: I am facing the same problem when trying to install visual studio 2015 Professional on Windows 10

Answer (score 29):

My installation was stuck for 2 days.
I fixed it this way:

- open the Task Manager (taskmgr.exe) and use the *Details* tab. I had two vs_community.exe instances running.
- I've used the command "Analyze wait chain" to inspect them. One of the instances was locked in waiting for an EnableGraphicsTools.exe process. I killed the process EnableGraphicsTools.exe and my installation resumed and was successful.

Comment: I had same issue. Two vs_community.exe were running. One with 50Mb of ram and second with about 4. Killed the later one.

Comment: @Rafał.S Your suggestion won't work for VS 2015 update 3,it will stop the installation as failed

Comment: In my case, by doing so, the installation was completed. although it said the option files were not successfully installed!

Answer (score 14):

In my case the vs_community.exe was stuck waiting on enableaspnet.exe. I killed it and the install process continued.

Comment: thanks so much. It helps me wasting a couple of hours.

Answer (score 7):

Get the iso for vs community edition and turn the internet off. Issue resolved by doing this way

Comment: Probably didn't work for someone and they think they're the center of the universe.

Comment: it won't install some components, asking for internet connection lately, when you reboot and install these components issues with stuck processes will appear again

Answer (score 3):

I disabled my AVG Internet Security 2015 for until next restart. Solved the issue.
Best luck

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem - disabling AVG helped. I had this problem when installing VS2015 on clean Win10 computer and I found, that AVG for some reason blocked all installations (not only VS2015) that are using msiexec.

Answer (score 2):

I just disabled the internet connection for the period of the installation (installing from an offline ISO file, of course) and the process went through fine. FYI.

Comment: this is supposed to be a comment not answer. and you have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Why can't this be an answer?? Also goes for the answered after mine that you've devoted too. The asker presented his problem, I had a similar problem with the installation of the VS15 and when I did it offline (cutting the internet connection and working from the pre-downloaded ISO file), the installation completed successfully. I really don't understand what is wrong with this kind of an answer. Please elaborate.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might help you in giving a good answer that will help other users in future. check the section `Answer the question`. And this answer looks like trail and error. You didn't explain it properly and you update your answer i'll definitely upvote. @TheCubeMan

Comment: Thanks!  Temporarily disabled internet using airplane mode - super quick solution w/o searching for the offending sub-process.

Answer (score 2):

I have been researching this issue and I am really surprised, that most of the folks trying to install Visual Studio 2015 or one of its update are not aware that all they have to do is run the setup as an admin with the /NoWeb argument and the setup will succeed in reasonable time.

The real culprit is not the setup itself, but that it tries to download and apply optional items not included in the .iso file. Ofcourse if you use the websetup to install the product, you do get a feedback on the main core items that are initially installed, and all those items are available in the iso, which can be easily downloaded. But the other optional items can only be applied by the setup by downloading and then be installed.

So I simple use the /Layout argument to the Visual Studio setup to cache all the items offline, then I use either /NoWeb or disconnect from internet or both to ensure that I can install all my components ok.

Please note that I have personally tried this, i.e. using the /NoWeb and/or disconnecting from internet and/or using the /Layout to download the whole deal and then running the setup offline.

Comment: What do you mean by `&|`? If this is an abbreviation of the English word `and`, please just use the word.

Comment: It's an abbreviation of And/Or

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2015 installer hangs during install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install) - just kill some of the background processes. I kill some of the windows installers(during the installation) and everything continues normally.

Comment: I had 2 instances of EnableAspNet.exe running in background processes. I ended one of them and installation resumed

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue. My Visual Studio 2015 Professional installation is stuck for hours. I used Analyze Wait Chain command in task manager as suggested above. There it showed me VSCommunity.exe is waiting for WUSP.exe process. so i manually stopped WUSP.exe process. My visual studio installation resumed now. It is running fine. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable cpu `SpeedStep` feature in BIOS.

this was my solution instead of disabling AV, disconnecting from internet and all other suggestion that I tested. after disabling SpeedStep I saw lot more speed in setup progress too.

Comment: I think the reboot is what did it. I only rebooted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 I go it through restarting Windows in Safe Mode! It's only way when my installation was fast as possible and avoid any hangs/stucks.

But don't forget to [start Windows Installer Service](https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/windows-installer-safe-mode) before VS setup.