# Visual Studio 2015 download getting stuck at applying Microsoft ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, installation

I'm currently on my third attempt trying to install Visual Studio 2015 on this computer. I have tried rebooting, hard shut downs, canceling setup and restarting, etc. Each time, it gets stuck at applying Microsoft ASP.net. I have tried leaving it overnight (12 hours). My download speed is 50-60 MBPS according to Ookla Speedtest. I am running Windows 10. I did do a "custom" installation and added C++, Python, and the Git extension. If I am not mistaken it said 7 GB size. Why is it doing this? Please help!

I don't understand why this isn't working because I installed VS 2015 for my laptop (a different computer) just a few days ago on a relatives WIFI and their speed was 3-7 MBPS.

[image]

(Note: The installer is not technically frozen since the loading dots on the bottom are moving.) However, bar hasn't filled up at all for like 6 hours.

EDIT:
Do I need ASP.NET (for C#, Python, and maybe C++)? Can I uncheck certain features for installation so that it wont try to install this? Also, when I cancel installation it never cancels and just stays there so I have to kill the installer with the task manager. This is getting incredibly frustrating.

Comment: try to contact with Microsoft support client. It's better solution to solve the problem.

Comment: @W92 okay I'll give that a shot. Are these the forums you are talking about: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it to work, it wasn't perfect, but here is what I did: It was getting stuck at very certain points, most notably ASP.NET. I did a little research and got an idea from something I read (I unfourtunetly can't find the source again). Sometimes windows opens invisible "confirm" type windows or installer windows that get stuck. When the installer got stuck I opened up task manager -> details, than checked On the visual studio process by right clicking then clicking analyzing wait chain. This showed me what process the VS install was waiting for. Then, I'd just kill the process. Messy, I know, but better then nothing. I had to do that 2 or 3 times. Afterward it said it installed correctly with 2 components that had warnings. ASP.NET was included. But everything else worked fine (c#, C++) Later I went back and did a repair. That worked pretty smooth. Finally, I installed the Python Tools successfully. (that part is sort of irrelevant but the point was that everything is now working fine).

edit, found another source: [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Installation Stuck In Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772347/visual-studio-2015-community-edition-installation-stuck-in-windows-10/33472773#33472773)

Comment: Thanks, fixed it for me. "vs_enterprise.exe" was waiting for "enableaspnet.exe" which I just killed to make the installation go on.

Comment: Another way (simpler imo) to kill the process is via powershell: run `get-process -name vs*`, and then Stop-Process for whichever installer task it's stuck on.  E.g., `Stop-Process -Name vs14*`

Answer (score 30):

Fixed it...

Easiest way is "threaten" to shut down the computer.  Go into Power, restart system.  You will be warned that there is a logging program which will not let the system reset.  Cancel that program and then do NOT restart.

Installer immediately went on to next part and finished install after having been stuck for 6 hours...

Comment: This is very similar to what I did, probably the same method. Good thinking on that one, I never even considered threatening restart.

Comment: Good thinking. Worked straight away for me. It's real a shame you seem to have to do weird tricks like this with a lot of Microsoft's products lately. Dreadful.

Comment: I so much want to up-vote this multiple times, not because it worked (although it did) but just because I love the use of language "'threaten' to shut down the computer".

Comment: Thanks That's a perfect hack

Answer (score 6):

Yes i had this problem too. To solve this open **task manager** and go to **details tab** then search for **TiWorker.exe**, **right click** on it and choose **analyzing wait chain** it will display many instances of the process that are in waiting mode , **check all those processes** and **terminate** them after doing this the installer will go to the next step.

Comment: Hi Simo, welcome to SO. Thanks for writing an answer. But make sure you read all the other answers on the question before posting your own, someone else might have already said this like in the case of this question. My answer is this almost exactly.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this problem, you have to install IIS first.

**Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Select "Internet Information Services" -> OK**

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a couple of hours before writing this answer and what worked for me was:
I **opened other programs at least two or three** and went to power and **clicked on restart** as usual it will warn you about open programs that need too be closed before shutdown or programs that are currently active I then **clicked on force close** and it closed the first program that I recently opened **then I quickly clicked on cancel**. Two minutes later instalation was back on track

Comment: Yup, another one of those weird little things that makes stuff work on Windows. Honestly, I have no idea why I don't have a Linux flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc, then go to Tiworker.exe and terminate all the waiting processes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this headache of a process to install Visual Studio. If you have tried everything and nothing seams to be working for you even by trying the command line shell then try this.

Go open task manager while running the installer and kill wusa.exe. It will kill the process to search for the update and continue the installation. You may have to kill some other processes as well if they get stuck. Its not great but it seams to be working.

wusa.exe seams to be the task that is the problem that prevents the installer from moving to the next step. This could be because your computer can not reach the update server.

This seams to be the case for both the Community and Enterprise Version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok thanks Jaxon. I've already got my VS working but hopefully this helps someone else.