# visual studio 15 installation

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I have been installing visual studio 15 for about 12 hours. 
[image]

before the moment on the screen above(microsoft visual c++ 2015 x64 debug runtime) it took only 2 hours, but after that it is still in process.

Comment: Did you check all the boxes in the beginning? If you did you are probably just downloading stuff

Comment: I did not check all,as   left unchecked all boxes about mobile development.

Comment: @Vitrum, does your issue is solved or not? If not, you can update your current issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since the installation hang on the update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3165756), you can cancel this installation, then download the [KB3165756](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx) and manually install it. After that, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software, then re-run the VS installer as administrator.

If this issue persists, you can have a look at [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582058/visual-studio-2015-download-getting-stuck-at-applying-microsoft-asp-net) and try the following methods:

1. Go to Task Manager, see if there the task of VS and kill all, restart the computer, then re-run the installer as administrator.
2. Forcibly shut down your computer, so the process is killed and you get a reboot, the installer process will start again.
3. Open Task Manager in detail mode--> Go to the "Details" tab--> Right Click the VisualStudio Process-->Click on the "Analyze wait chain". You will see the name of the process which is responsible for the wait. Kill this process and the installation maybe process quickly.