# Does the Visual Studio 2015 installer download some selected features from Microsoft?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise from an ISO image (4GB) on my PC.

By the time I selected all the options I wanted in the installer this amounted to ~35GB of required disk space (yes, I did wonder at what magic was being used to squeeze 35GB of binaries onto a 4GB ISO).

Eventually the installer loitered around this part of the install for a good while:

> Applying:
>
> [ Progress bar ]
>
> Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.240

(Can't get a screenshot to upload right now)

Are these (and some other features - e.g. the Android bits) being installed from the mounted Visual Studio ISO image, or are these being downloaded from Microsoft by the installer?

The reason I ask is because:

- My internet connection slowed down to a crawl (sadly I am in a rural area so capped at 8Mbits until the sky falls in).
- Upon noticing the above I checked the metering on my internet connection and it suggests I've consumed around 1GB of data in the past hour or so while the installer was running. There's nothing else downloading or streaming content at the moment.

There's certainly no indication from the installer that it would source some features from online rather than the ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  All the Xamarin files are downloaded from Xamarin servers. The emulators for Windows Mobile 240 came out after VS was 'shipped' so they would not be included in the ISO.

The only other indication is when the top progress bar says 'Acquiring' and it goes quick, it is from the ISO, otherwise it is being downloaded.

You are right the installer should indicate which items will be downloaded and which ones are on the ISO.  Something MS should add.

Comment: The only "Acquiring" stage that happened was at the start of the install, and that took around 2 mins. Certainly not enough time to download a ~GB of extras such as the Emulators. It was during the "Applying" stage I noticed all my somewhat limited bandwidth being soaked up. The principle of least surprise is most definitely being bent here.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO installer does download a number of components from the Internet. However, it does this during the "Acquiring" stage. During the "Applying" stage it's installing the component. If it's stuck on applying something then you've probably encountered some problem other than slow Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot magically expand 4 GB of data to 32 GB. Some of the core files are included in the ISO. The rest is downloaded. For example the latest Visual C++ SDK and .NET Framework is included. But your Visual Studio (on your platform) might support an older version of the Framework as well. If you selected those, they will be downloaded.

Emulators are by default, always downloaded. This is because of licensing, packaging and security issues. An emulator confirming to the latest SDK **is** included in the ISO. But its barely usable without internet updates.

The reason why it takes up so much space, is because of Microsoft's habit of allowing code repetition if it solves SDK version problems. For example 8.0 and 8.1 SDKs contain a lot of common code. But they still exist as two separate folders. This solves a lot of problems when switching between target platforms. What you should know is that a lot of this code contains configuration files suited to your local environment. This is generated on the fly.

---

With reference to long **"applying"** time while the installer is processing Emulators, this has been a [long standing problem in Visual Studio installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install). I wasn't really interested in the emulators while my installation was taking place. So I resorted to unsafe practices and terminated processes till it sped up. It did screw up my emulators, but Microsoft applications are smart enough to fix themselves with quick updates at first run.