# Can't uninstall or repair Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uninstallation, repair

I've tried repair/uninstall, the same from an ISO and the same from the web installer with no result. The program starts the "repair"/"uninstall" and freezes at the very begining. And when I try to close it the same, the animation of "im doing sth" continues but nothing happens,

I was using MV 2015 com for a while, then an error appeared telling me the license has expired, and then I couldnt open the program, repair or uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio, reboot and uninstall again. Worked for me. Keep in mind this will blow away all your Visual Studio editions, so if you need multiple versions, only delete the sub-folder corresponding to the edition to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you:
[Visual Studio 2015 installer hangs during install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install)

I have the same problem , I have avg antivirus on my computer, I disabled him and then the uninstall completed.