# Stuck while installing Visual Studio 2015 (Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2999226))

Tags: visual-studio, windows-update

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 to my Windows 7. I seem to get stuck in this screen while installing it. It has been like 3 hours now and still stuck. Tried installing that update manually but had no luck since it just kept loading as well (Searching for updates).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install

Comment: After overcoming this issue using this thread it got stuck further for another hotfix KB2664825. I killed `wusa.exe` to go past the second hurdle.

Comment: What do you mean by "killed"? In the task manager? I'm having this same issue

Comment: @RBT thank you bro for that hotfix issue :) "wusa.exe" was the culprit

Answer (score 9):

The same thing happened to me. Here is what I did in order to get it successfully installed. I downloaded KB2999226 update from Microsofts website here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49093

After installing this package, I started the installation process again. That worked for me.

Comment: After installing this KB article manually I faced another issue on Windows 7 SP 1 which has been solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187066/visual-studio-15-preview-5-license-expiration-issue).

Answer (score 9):

I would like to give you a background on Universal CRT this would help you in understanding as to why the system should be updated before installing vc_redist.x64.exe.
A large portion of the C-runtime moved into the OS in Windows 10 (ucrtbase.dll) and is serviced just like any other OS DLL (e.g. kernel32.dll).  It is no longer serviced by Visual Studio directly.  MSU packages are the file type for Windows Updates.

In order to get the Windows 10 Universal CRT to earlier OSes, Windows Update packages were created to bring this OS component downlevel.  KB2999226 brings the Windows 10 RTM Universal CRT to downlevel platforms (Windows Vista through Windows 8.1).  KB3118401 brings Windows 10 November Update to the Universal CRT to downlevel platforms.

Windows XP (latest SP) is an exception here.  Windows Servicing does not provide downlevel packages for that OS, so Visual Studio (Visual C++) provides a mechanism to install the UCRT into System32 via the VCRedist and MSMs.

1.The Windows Universal Runtime is included in the VC Redist exe package as it has dependency on the Windows Universal Runtime (KB2999226).
Windows 10 is the only OS that ships the UCRT in-box.  All prior OSes obtain the UCRT via Windows Update only.  This applies to all Vista->8.1 and associated Server SKUs.

For Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 the Windows Universal Runtime must be installed via KB2999226. However it has a prerequisite update KB2919355 which contains updates that facilitate installing the KB2999226 package.

2. Why does KB2999226 not always install when the runtime is installed from the redistributable?  What could prevent KB2999226 from installing as part of the runtime?
   The UCRT MSU included in the VCRedist is installed by making a call into the Windows Update service and the KB can fail to install based upon Windows Update service activity/state:
   1)  If the machine has not updated to the required servicing baseline, the UCRT MSU will be viewed as being “Not Applicable”.
   Ensure KB2919355 is installed. Also, there were known issues with KB2919355  so before this the following hotfix should be installed.
   KB2939087
   KB2975061
   2)            If the Windows Update service is installing other updates when the VCRedist installs, you can either see long delays or errors indicating the machine is busy.
   a.            This one can be resolved by waiting and trying again later (which may be why installing via Windows Update UI at a later time succeeds).
   3)            If the Windows Update service is in a non-ready state, you can see errors reflecting that.
   a.            We recently investigated a failure with an error code indicating the WUSA service was shutting down.
3. To identify if the prerequisite KB2919355 is installed there are 2 options:
   Registry key:
   64bit hive
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14
   CurrentState = 112
   32bit hive
   HKLM\SOFTWARE[WOW6432Node]Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14
   CurrentState = 112

Or check the file version of:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wuaueng.dll
C:\Windows\System32\wuaueng.dll
7.9.9600.17031  or later

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck with the same problem. I found this page with all the possible versions of the KB2999226 also know as Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2999226

I download the x64 version and it work perfectly in my Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

Today i also face this type of problem during visual studio 2015 Community installation. As i have 64bit OS. I used https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49093  link to update  KB2999226 mannualy.

Try It. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me and I got it working doing this:

- Do not cancel the installation (using the cancel button), instead force showdown your computer so the process is killed and you get a reboot.
- After the reboot, just start the install process again.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just kill `wusa.exe` and install KB2999226 manually. Installation will continue without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem after installing clean Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit OS,

When I search about KB2999226 install fails during Visual Studio I also saw that I couldn't install any other updates.

By the way, I found a solution. When formatting some PCs with ( maybe ) partly corrupted bootable media, first Update for windows not completely installed.

As a solution;

1- Disable update for windows from Control Panel.

2- Restart your pc.

3- Install KB3102810 windows update. ( First update for Windows )

Microsoft TR links;

( 64 bit ) https://www.microsoft.com/tr-TR/download/details.aspx?id=49540

( 32 bit ) https://www.microsoft.com/tr-TR/download/details.aspx?id=49542

4- Restart your pc via finished setup.

5- Try getting updates, or manually setup KB2999226.

I could install this way.

Have a nice days.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by the following steps : 
1. Disable windows updates(but check the option "let users install updates manually")
2. Reboot the PC
3. Manually install **kb2999226** update from VS install folder (packages/Patch/x64/Windows6.1-KB299926-x64.msu)
4. Start the VS install
5. After install is finished turn back automatic updates

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today, stuck on the kb2999226 for over an hour.  First, i thought it is because i am using a VM on my local machine.  But decided to cancel the installation, then install kb2999226 first, then install the vs2015 community again, it works out much better, the installation move forward and progressing.
thx.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to turn off Internet connection, reboot and restart VS installation. Without Internet connectivity VS installer won't try to update Windows first and will continue without delay.