# Visual Studio 15 Preview 5 : License expiration issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 15 Preview 5 on my office pc successfully and signed in with my hotmail account into it. There it says the license for this pre-release software is licensed to my hotmail account which will end on 31 January 2017 as shown below:

[image]

When I installed the same Visual Studio 15 Preview 5 on my home pc and tried setting up the same hotmail account then it gives licensing error. It says

> License: Prerelease software. Your license has expired.

[image]

Is anyone aware of such an issue? Is there any limitation on configuring Visual Studio 15 preview 5 build on several machines with same live id?

Comment: Have the same issue, but I've only installed it on a single machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue - it seams that the installer doesn't finish successfully. 
Starting the installer again told me that it was interrupted.
Running the installer solved the issue for me.

Take a hat de discussions here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/05/announcing-visual-studio-15-preview-5/

Comment: yes. I can see people talking about the very same issue in the comment thread. Let me give a try by reinstalling it once and I will let  you know the outcome.

Comment: This worked for me finally.I uninstalled and then reinstalled entire stuff and then I logged in with my hotmail id and it worked. One additional thing I did. As I was seeing that VS 15 Preview 5 had the burden to install lot of components. So after uninstalling malfunctioning VS 15 Preview 5, I first installed VS 2015 Update 3 Community Edition. There after I installed VS 15 Preview 5. This time the whole installation also took very less time as it found lot of components pre-installed.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, this error was solved after I've restarted Windows to install the updates. When I logged in after the system restart, VS 15 Preview 5 installer has auto-started and finished its job - and my VS 15 installation is fully working since then.