# How do I fix Visual Studio 2015 installion when it hangs?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 installer suspended for a long time.

How do I solve the problem?

[image]

> Microsoft Visual Studio Services Hub : 安装时发生严重错误
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23918 : Package failed.

**Then** I change to use **Iso** file. there is an error as follow:

[image]

Is there a way to remove visual studio 2015 manually? such as the [TotalUninstall](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/files/220137/TotalUninstaller.zip) Tool.

Comment: One of the possible causes is if you're installing from a network drive and it becomes unavailable even for a short while. In any case, it's been asked many times before. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install

Comment: Not 100% sure about the update 2 installation but would like to share my experience. try to kill the 'secondaryinstaller.exe' process and see if installation goes ahead.