# Visual Studio Community 2015 where is the ISO to download?

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 7 x64 after multiple troubles. The solution was to reset my notebook, update all I can on Windows Update, stop the antivirus and then install Visual Studio Community 2015

Now I need Visual Studio Community 2015 on another notebook, almost the same model and nothing works. I tryed most of the tips from this post

[Visual Studio 2015 installer hangs during install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788574/visual-studio-2015-installer-hangs-during-install)

and nothing. Allways stuck on kb2999226 thing.

Some users talks about installing from the ISO but on the official link

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

I don't find the ISO, only the web installer file.

**Where can I download the Visual Studio Community 2015 ISO?**

Comment: Check again. The "Choose Format" option has two radio buttons - Web Installer and ISO

Comment: PS when running into issues, adding/removing/cleaning stuff without knowing what you are doing or why is *guaranteed* to lead to more serious issues. VS 2015 Community has no compatibility issues with Windows 7 or 64-bit OSs. "Nothing works" is not an error description either. In any case, if stopping your antivirus program solves the issue, you should probably find a different antivirus, and probably file a bug with the vendor

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The link https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs on my browser it did´t show any option, just the link to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691978&clcid=0x40a that's why ask. Maybe is not available for spanish region?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Stopping my AVG Free antivirus worked on one notebook but not on the other. "Allways stuck on kb2999226 thing" that's the problem I have. Thanks.

Comment: That's not the link you posted in the question. Check again the link you posted in the question. As for AVG, try a different antivirus. If the antivirus is causing problems, it's the antivirus that needs fixing

Comment: Finally, the link in the comments is the landing page, not the download page. Click on the Downloads menu and go to the All Downloads section

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know but I tried  the All Downloads before and I can´t find any ISO or radio button option. Maybe is not available por spanish users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) you provided, you have to click on Visual Studio 2015 and then select radio button ISO and then press download, everything should go fine
[image]

Comment: thanks I understand but on my browsers Chrome, Internet Explorer or Mozilla when I click on "Download Community Free" I don't have another option, just the web installer. Maybe is a limitation to my country? South America

Comment: Now is working !!! thanks a lot. It was something with my browser. I reset Google Chrome and now I'm downloading the ISO. Thanka, Answer accepted.